# Keep record of NFTs minted counter by each user

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, candy-machine-v2

I want to keep record of NFTs minted by each user separately. I am currently maintaining a counter to keep record of all NFTs minted.

Account:

```
#[account]
pub struct NFTsMinted {
    //net NFTs minted
    pub count: u32,
}
```

Derived Account:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ModifyNFTsMinted<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub minting_account: Account<'info, NFTsMinted>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub wallet: Signer<'info>,
}
```

Minting Function:

```
 pub fn mint_nft(
        ctx: Context<ModifyNFTsMinted>,
    ) -> Result<()> {
       
        let ledger_account = &mut ctx.accounts.minting_account;
        minting_account.count += 1;
        OK();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can create a new pda account similar to NFTs Minted, it will be derived from user ID and keep a vector of nft mint IDs. With every new mint you can push the mint id in the vector.

If you want to know which user minted a particular NFT you can obtain that information from the metadata

Comment: Bro, any code snippet that you can share?